# Load error while creating new Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

When creating new Rails app I get this error

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': libcrypto.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.9/bin/rails:8:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.9/bin/rails:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/bin/rails:19:in `load'
  from /share/Ruby/192p290/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Error says 'No such file or directory' but file exists.

```
[~] # cd /share/Ruby/192p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest && ls 
bubblebabble.so* rmd160.so*       sha2.so*
md5.so*          sha1.so*
```

versions:
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [armv5tel-linux-eabi]
Rails 3.0.9
gem 1.3.7

Ruby is installed from source in custom directory and added to $PATH.

Edit:
Forgot to mention it that I'm trying to install it on QNAP TS-412. It's running on arm linux.

Edit:
Managed to install RVM. Installed ruby 1.9.2 p320 and still getting error.

```
/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Edit:
Uninstalled RVM and installed ruby again from source. Still getting error.

File `md5.so` does exist

```
[/share/Web] # cd /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest/
[/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest] # ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x    1 admin    administ    12338 May 10 19:56 bubblebabble.so*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 admin    administ    17847 May 10 19:56 md5.so*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 admin    administ    27764 May 10 19:56 rmd160.so*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 admin    administ    23159 May 10 19:56 sha1.so*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 admin    administ    39475 May 10 19:56 sha2.so*
```

Edit:
Ruby somehow is not linked to crypto library correctly.

```
ruby -e 'require "digest/md5"'
```

This throws same error.

Any idea how to make link?

**Edit:**

Tried to make links to libraries using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export RUBYLIB=/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest:$RUBYLIB
```

but i don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Do a `ls -l` on that directory - is md5.so perhaps a link to a non-existing file?

Comment: @Thilo File does exist. It was there in every attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly solved.

```
ln -s /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend installing Ruby using RVM. The custom install of Ruby you have might have not be linked in to the crypto library correctly.

Here's a link to the rvm site: https://rvm.io/

Instructions for installation are here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Also, I've found installing supporting libraries using brew to generally give better results.

Here's a pointer to a set of scripts maintained by Thoughtbot (a leading Rails consulting group) for setting up a new Mac with everything required for running Rails.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop/blob/master/mac

Follow the steps there (at least those that apply) and you should have good luck.

Comment: Thanks, already tried it, and whole lot of another problems appeared. Forgot to mention it that I'm trying to install it on QNAP TS-412. It's running on arm linux. It was hard enough to install ruby, and now this. Well did learn a lot of stuff on the way.

Comment: Managed to install via RVM and still getting error. Tried different versions of Ruby and same error appears. Really stuck here.

Comment: Ruby is definitly not linked to crypto library.
ruby -e 'require "digest/md5"' throws same error.